# Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: json4s-ast,json4s-core

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, ignite

I'm trying to use the ignite-spark dependency in my sbt project.
Here is the build.sbt file:

```
name := "App"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.xerial.snappy" % "snappy-java" % "1.1.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.10" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" % "ignite-spark_2.10" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" % "ignite-spring" % "2.2.0"
```

But when I try to compile, I get a cross-version suffixes error for the following dependencies:

```
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-ast _2.10, _2.11
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-core _2.10, _2.11
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.json4s:json4s-core
```

I believe it might be related to this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3710

But I thought it was solved already.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug from the ignite-spark_2.10 module.

1) I cloned the ignite project repository: https://github.com/apache/ignite

2) Downgraded it to version 2.2.0

3) Changed the pom.xml from the spark_2.10 module like so:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
    <artifactId>json4s-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
```

4) Compiled and packaged a new Jar.
5) Voilà, it works.

I informed the Ignite community via the mailing list.

Comment: They haven't fixed this yet. I'm still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed under the following ticket: [IGNITE-3084](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3084)

Try upgrading to Ignite 2.4 or newer. It should resolve the issue.

Related JIRA ticket: [IGNITE-6369](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6369)